# dropzonejs preview container

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I am trying to use dropzonejs first time and having an issue with preview container.

when I drag image it goes at end of form even my image container is at top of the form.

1. How can I see the preview of the image in DIV dropzoneDragArea or dropzone-previews, not in some random place of form
2. How can I remove and add buttons, as I need to submit an image with form

Thanks so much for the help.

here is what I am doing, I have added dropzone.js file
I have bellow HTML code for the dropzone

```
<form role="form" id="form" class="dropzone dropzone-manual" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">

<div class="col-md-6">
<div id="dropzoneDragArea" class="dz-default dz-message dz-clickable">
<span>Attach Receipt</span>
</div>
<div class="dropzone-previews" id="dropzone-previews"></div>

<input type="number" class="form-control" name="amount" id="amount">

<button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info">
```

here is JS

```
<script>
$(function(){
  Dropzone.options.dropzoneDragArea = {
    maxFiles: 1,
    maxFilesize: 5,
    acceptedFiles: 'image/*',
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    autoDiscover: false,
    paramName: 'prod_pic',
    previewsContainer: '#dropzoneDragArea',
    clickable:'#dropzoneDragArea'
  };
});
</script>
```

this is my CSS , in case if you need this too

```
<style>
#dropzoneDragArea {
    background-color: #fbfdff;
    border: 1px dashed #c0ccda;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.dropzone-manual.dropzone .dz-message {
    margin-top: 0;
}
.dropzone .dz-message {
    margin-top: 45px;
    color: #03a9f4;
}
.dropzone .dz-message {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 2em 0;
}
.dropzone, .dropzone * {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.dropzone, .dropzone * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
</style>
```